A fan appears to take a care of a blind idol
I only remember the main outline, and most likely it wasn't the sole focus of the movie. More of a sub-plot or perhaps a sub-story in an omnibus. 
There's an entartainer (could be an idol/actress/singer), who loses her sight (either due to an assault or an illness). She is forgotten by the show-biz world, until one day a fan appears before her and proclaims that he'll care for her from now on (he may or may not confess his love as well at that point). 
Genre: Drama, seemed Shunji Iwai-esque in style,
Production date: late 90s/early 2000s
Any ideas?

One of the 3 stories in Takashi Kitano's Dolls from 2002 is about a female pop idol whose face is disfigured in an accident (she loses an eye) and she becomes a recluse. A devoted fan then blinds himself and she allows him into her life. Could this be it? Here's the trailer.
